# Dynamic admin submenu

Tags: plugins, menus, wp-admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page

I'm creating a plugin for WordPress with dynamic sub-menu's fetched from the server. Putting the dynamic loading of sub-menu's into the `menu_setup()` hook function would slow down other WordPress operations and should only execute once user clicks/selects the `top level menu item`, but the `add_submenu_page(...)` function are not executing/showing up in `menu_init()` hook.

Here is my example code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menu_setup');

function menu_setup()

    // Creates a top-level Menu item.
    add_menu_page( 'Chur', 'Chur', 'manage_options', 'chur-plugin', 'menu_init');
}

function menu_init(){

    // Dynamic submenu 
    add_submenu_page( 'chur-plugin', 'Chur 1', 'Chur 1', 'manage_options', 'chur_1', 'menu_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'chur-plugin', 'Chur 2', 'Chur 2', 'manage_options', 'chur_2', 'menu_page' );
    add_submenu_page( 'chur-plugin', 'Chur 3', 'Chur 3', 'manage_options', 'chur_3', 'menu_page' );
    ...

}

function menu_page(){ //Show page content };
```

Is there a way around this? or a limitation to WordPress?

Comment: Is there a way around a problem caused by putting something that does something you haven't explained into a function? Can you try to expand upon this question please?

Comment: I have updated my answer to be more clear.